# Класс File и каталоги

Tags: java, io

Сейчас изучаю ввод-вывод, столкнулся с таким понятие как каталог, не очень понимаю что это, можете объяснить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В файловой системе, каталог (или папка) это место для хранения файлов.
Класс File в Java содержит функции для работы с каталогами.

В частности создать каталог можно при помощи функции mkdir, если операция выполнена успешно, то возвращается true, а если что-то пошло не так, то false. В данном классе имеются и другие полезные функции для работы с каталогом-папкой.

Если каталог доступен только для чтения это значит, что из него можно только читать, то есть в него нельзя добавлять новые файлы и подкаталоги, а если доступен для записи, то можно добавлять новые файлы и подкаталоги (то есть простые каталоги, в которые можно добавлять файлы и подкаталоги и так далее)

Comment: Это файл с пометкой "каталог" ))

Answer (score 1):

"[Каталог](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3_(%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0))" это "папка", она же "директория".

В синей рамке - каталоги. В зеленой - файлы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не подскажите?  Как понять: Доступно для чтения и доступно для записи (класс File)?